# How to find a change in role

Tags: human-resources, work-experience, manager

If we are working a role which we weren't suitable for and looking for a change and if our boss is not cooperative. What shall we do? While contacting HR, if the response is like **"Business will have an impact, so we cannot change your role"**. How will I take this? please don't suggest to Resign :)

Comment: "please don't suggest to Resign" Why not?

Comment: You should resign straight away.

Comment: Is your loyalty to the company worth more to you than your happiness? That seems like the only reason why you would consider resigning not to be an option. If so, remember that a company is only worth your loyalty if they are loyal to you: you are more productive when you're happy, so if they don't care that you're not happy now, then they are not loyal to you.

Comment: that's so true . Happiness is the greatest factor !!!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're fighting *both* your manager and HR on this, your chances of managing to change role in your current organisation are probably zero. Therefore you have two options:

- Continue in your current role
- Find a job in a different organisation

I know that's not what you want to hear, but sometimes it's just the case you can't have everything you want.

Answer (score 5):

> How will I take this?

Take it as a 'No'